# Doing it right in Django - subclassing instead of hacking

Tags: django, subclassing

I am using the threadedcomments module and need two changes:
- an additional field on the ThreadedComment model
- different fields on the form

I know the answer is to subclass but I'm not sure how to go about doing this - where does the code go?

Comment: Where did you get threadedcomments module? Is it from django.contrib.comments?

Comment: I think he's talking about http://code.google.com/p/django-threadedcomments/

Comment: Yes I'm using django-threadedcomments, but the link from harshh applies just as well.  I've subclassed the model, just trying the form...

Comment: You should be able to just subclass the form in the same way, and make your new module listed as COMMENTS_APP.  The only other thing that you might have to re-write is the templatetags if you are wanting to use that.  Other than that, should just need models/forms.

Comment: Had to do some changes to the template tags but not too onerous as using only small bit of functionality.  Thanks for all your support.

Comment: @PhoebeB Can you share with me the steps you took to do this with django-threadedcomments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its not clear from you question. I am assuming you are talking about extending *django.contrib.comments* .

Yes you have to subclass it. Create your own application, and all code (extended models, forms, views etc.) goes there.

Important things, you wont add *django.contrib.comments* in **INSTALLED_APPS** list, but add your comment application name(which you inherit from *django.contrib.comments*).

Also you would need to add

```
COMMENTS_APP = 'my_comment_app'
```

to your **settings.py**

Here is very good [example](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/custom/#an-example-custom-comments-app) for doing exactly what you want to do.